Shrink spacing in letter (\vspace not working)
This is time sensitive as I am trying to submit a job application today.
My cover letter just barely goes onto the 2nd page. I want to reduce the space between my name and the date, the date and the opening, and between the closing and my name. I've tried moving some \vspace*{-numberpt}


\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[margin=1in, top=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\address{My name}
\title{cover letter}
\signature{My name}

\linespread{1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{}
    

%\vspace*{-.5in}
\opening{Dear Mr.\ Job person,} 


\lipsum[1-6]


\closing{Thank you,}


\end{letter}

\end{document}


You can avoid the problem by not using \linespread. If you must use it, use setspace or setspaceenhanced to limit it to the body so you're not stretching the spaces you then want to reduce.
